# XML - Specify the type of an element containing children as string in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to create an `XSD` for an existing `XML` file. The `XML` contains a block like:

```
<Coords>
          <Coord1>L1:  50,L2: 9 </Coord1>
          <Coord2>L1:  51,L2: 19 </Coord2>
          <Coord3>L1:  521,L2: 29 </Coord3>
          <Coord4>L1:  53,L2: 39 </Coord4>
          <Coord5>L1:  54,L2: 49 </Coord5>
          <Coord6>L1:  55,L2: 59 </Coord6>
</Coords>
```

Since the number of co-ordinates is not a fixed count, I am trying to specify the type of `Coords` as `xs:string` in the `XSD`. What modification should be made to the `xml` so that it can be validated based on that `XSD`?

When I tried to validate the XML using the XSD in Notepad++, I get the error as `Coords': Element content is not allowed, because the type definition is simple.`

The XSD part is:

```
<xs:element name="Coords" type="xs:string"/>
```

Comment: You could use [restriction](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_restriction.asp) of string type with regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Use [restriction](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_restriction.asp) of string type. For example:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Point">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="L1\:\s?\d+,\s?L2\:\s?\d+"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Then it is possible to be applied to your `Coord` elements:

```
<xs:element name="Coords">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Coord" type="Point" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: @Jackzz, I advice you to use same names becouse the number of internal elements is unknown. You could get required element by index or use additional attribute.

Answer (score 0):

XSD tries to encourage good XML design rather than making it possible to describe any possible input document structure. Using element names coord1, coord2, coord3... is definitely not good XML design. (Much better would be `<coord nr="1"/>`, or even better, forget the number, since it is pure noise: if it weren't there, you could reconstruct it.)

So there's no way in XSD 1.0 to accurately say that `coords` has a sequence of children which are all named `coordX` where X is a number, let alone to say that X takes the values 1..n in order. You can do it using assertions in XSD 1.1, of course:

```
<xs:assert xpath="every $n in * satisfies (matches(name(), 'coord\d+')
and number(substring-after(name(), 'coord')) = count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
```

But reading your question again, it sounds as if you are prepared to modify the XML design. In that case, rename all the children as Coord, and define `Coords` with a complex type consisting of a sequence of `Coord` elements, each of which has type `xs:string`.